# How captcha can be tested in high requesting sitution (Load & Stress Testing)?

Tags: asp.net, session, viewstate, captcha, load-testing

I have a project implemented in ASP.NET and in requirements of this project Captcha is needed so I searched for a good Captcha and finally chosen one. 
That version of selected Captcha uses ViewState and after of some simple testing of its functionality it was selected, but because the load of site is high (1000 request per minute) this Captcha failed.
I conclude that I should load test it before using it but I faced to a question: How can I Load Test it when computer can not read the text!

And another question I have is: what's the difference between using ViewState and Session in Captcha?(If you know a good Captcha -Except Recaptcha, because it is very complicated to read by human(!!!)- please inform me about it.)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well, ViewState is public available (it is in the HTML), so if you use ViewState, then it should be encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Recaptcha may be difficult to read, but that's one reason why it works. It can also definitely handle 1000 requests a minute. Youll probably find your requests going down after you implement a good captcha. Or have you considered asking users to register?

Answer (score 0):

You could easily set up a load test with JMeter for example, in case you provide your load testing tool with the url and the correct captcha result as a data pool (make sure to also include a few test cases where the wrong result is entered to have a realistic test).

You can then scale up the virtual users and see how the response time evolves.